Django - How to filter model objects by certain attribute and use it for front-end?
I am a beginner and building a website to showcase wines.
This is the model for Wine:
class Wine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/wines/')
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

I added a page called "Advanced Search" which should initially show all the wines. I want to implement filtering functionality so when I select the corresponding checkboxes, the wines should be filtered by their keywords. Currently the keyword field accepts string as input. For example Wine1 has the following keywords: "red, plum, citrus". But the keywords field accepting string is not necessary (please suggest other approaches if needed).
In my HTML file I added some checkboxes to test. The checkboxes correspond the keywords.
So if I check the "plum" and "red" checkboxes, only the wines which contain those keywords should be shown.
Here is the html part of the page:
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Filter
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="filterOptions">
            <li><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="redCheckbox" value="red"><label class="form-check-label" for="redCheckbox">Red</label></li>
            <li><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="sparklingCheckbox" value="sparkling"><label class="form-check-label" for="sparklingCheckbox">Sparkling</label></li>
            <li><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="whiteCheckbox" value="white"><label class="form-check-label" for="whiteCheckbox">White</label></li>
            <li><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="sweetCheckbox" value="sweet"><label class="form-check-label" for="sweetCheckbox">Sweet</label></li>
            <li><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="dryCheckbox" value="dry"><label class="form-check-label" for="dryCheckbox">Dry</label></li>
            <li><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="citrusCheckbox" value="citrus"><label class="form-check-label" for="citrusCheckbox">Citrus</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <section class="products section-padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {% for wine in page_obj %}
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 mb-3">
                    <div class="product-thumb">
                        <a href="product-detail.html">
                            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ wine.image.url }}" class="img-fluid product-image" alt="">
                        </a>

                        <div class="product-info d-flex">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="product-title mb-0">
                                    <a href="product-detail.html" class="product-title-link">{{ wine.name }}</a>
                                </h5>

                            <p class="product-p">{{ wine.description }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

And here is the view (which is very likely wrong)
def wines_all(request):
    all_wines = Wine.objects.all()

    selected_keywords = request.GET.getlist('keywords')

    # filter wines based on selected keywords
    filtered_wines = all_wines
    for keyword in selected_keywords:
        filtered_wines = filtered_wines.filter(keywords__icontains=keyword)

    paginator = Paginator(filtered_wines, 9)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    return render(request, 'test.html', {'page_obj': page_obj, 'selected_keywords': selected_keywords})

Any guidance or assistance would be appreciated.
Additional question: If needed or possible can I use javascript in my django project for filtering and django to implement the view?

Have you tried to use Q to create a custom query based on the selected_keywords?

You are resetting your filtered_wines value on every keyword here: filtered_wines = filtered_wines.filter(keywords__icontains=keyword)...you need to gather all keywords and write something more like: filtered_wines = filtered_wines.filter(keywords__in=[word for word in selected_keywords]) which gives you a filtered list of all keywords selected

@Toliak actually no I haven't, not familiar with it yet but I will look it up. Thanks
